# Spring Security Authorisation for Repository Query

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, authorization, spring-data

If I have a list of orders stored in a table and exposed through the url /orders/{id} and I want to restrict a principal from accessing an order by changing the path `id` in the url, how can Spring Security help me in querying the Spring Data JPA repository.

Based on Spring Security 4 youtube videos: -

```
interface OrderRepository extends Repository<Order, Long> {

    @Query("select o from Order o where o.id = ?1 and o.from.id = ?{#principal.id}  ")
    Optional<Order> findOrder(long id);
}
```

Is this the best practice? Ideally I would like to use the Spring Data method name feature and avoid rewriting the Query in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is @PreAuthorize or @PostAuthorize from spring security.  They are annotations for method level security in spring.  They will allow you to restricts based on role and other attributes.

```
interface OrderRepository extends Repository<Order, Long> {

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')") // Allows only users with admin privileges
@Query("select o from Order o where o.id = ?1 and o.from.id = ?{#principal.id}  ")
Optional<Order> findOrder(long id);
```

}

https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/04/spring-security-java-config-preview-method-security/

---

Edit:

If you looking to only return the Order if the current authenticated user is associated with who the order is from.

```
@PostAuthorize("returnObject.from == authentication.name")
Optional<Order> findOrder(long id);
```

You can use springs expression language with the @PreAuthorize @PostAuthorize annotations.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html

Hope this helps

---

Edit 2: You can use @PreFilter and @PostFilter to filter collections.

Example

```
@PostFilter("filterObject.from == authentication.name")
List<Order> findOrder(long id);
```

This will run through the list and only return Orders where from is the current authenticated user. You're also able to combine expressions.

```
@PostFilter("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or filterObject.from == authentication.name")
List<Order> findOrder(long id);
```

This will check if the current authenticated user has a role of ROLE_ADMIN.  If the user has that priviledge the unaltered list will be return else it'll filter and only return those orders where "from" is associated with the current authenticated user.

Comment: how can @PreAuthorize do authorisation at a per user basis, and not on a role basis please?

Comment: @aprofromindia edited my post.  PostAuthorize will check the from member variable of the returned Order object with the current authenticated user.

Comment: Cool how can we implement this logic for findAll() authorisation please. I dont want to use @PostFilter() and filter the whole list.

Comment: I updated my response but just read that you didn't want to use PostFilter.  I'm not sure of a way to do that without PostFilter